# EWS: Category management

Tags: java, exchange-server, ewsjavaapi

Is there a way to handle the management of categories in the ESW-(Java)-API? i.e. create, rename, modify, delete, change color, etc.

I cannot see a class in there but assume it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be possible:

[Add category](http://www.independentsoft.de/jwebservices/tutorial/addcategory.html)

[Get categories](http://www.independentsoft.de/jwebservices/tutorial/getcategories.html)

Comment: Yeah, thx, that's the only way. I thought it might be possible with the MS-libs directly...